# Obtener una fila con más de un campo en una consulta sin usar array

Tags: php

Tengo una clase en **PHP** donde obtengo un único registro, tengo dos campos en el *select*:

```
public function buscar() {
    $sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabla1 WHERE CONDICION limit 1";
    $bd = new Conn();
    $stmt = $bd->query($sql);
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $row;
}
```

Quiero asignar los valores de *campo1* y *campo2* a dos variables:

```
$tabla = new Tabla();
$valores = $tabla->buscar();
echo $valores ["campo1"];
echo $valores ["campo2"];
```

Pero me muestra este mensaje:

```
Notice: Undefined index: campo1
Notice: Undefined index: campo2
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?
El select solamente regresa un registro con dos campos, por ello no debería utilizar Array.

Comment: Porque `fetchColumn()` solo retorna una columna.  Intenta con `fetchAll()`

Comment: Actualicé mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchColumn` como su nombre lo indica te sirve para una columna (si ha varias te obtiene solamente la primera columna). Este método es útil para consultas que devuelven una sola columnas, como por ejemplo si quieres contar las filas que hay en la tabla.

Para varias columnas puedes usar [el método `fetch` con cualquiera de los `feth_style`  de que dispone](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Por ejemplo, si lo usas con `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` te crea un arreglo asociativo `columna => valor`

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabla1 WHERE CONDICION limit 1";
    $bd = new Conn();
    $stmt = $bd->query($sql);
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $campo1=$row["campo1"];
    $campo2=$row["campo2"];
    return $row;
?>
```

O por ejemplo si lo usas con `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` es parecido al anterior, pero puedes usar la notación de objetos, mucho más intuitiva y elegante:

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM tabla1 WHERE CONDICION limit 1";
    $bd = new Conn();
    $stmt = $bd->query($sql);
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $campo1=$row->campo1;
    $campo2=$row->campo2;
    return $row;
?>
```

Hay otros *fetch_style*, pero estos son los que se suelen usar para este tipo de casos.

Comment: Utilicé la segunda forma, pero la asignación de los valores los hice fuera de la clase.

Comment: @Piropeator claro, si se trata de un método, basta con retornar `$row` y en donde se reciba obtener los datos que hay dentro de `$row`, aquí te lo he puesto antes del `return` para explicar cómo hay que leer cada dato según el *fetch_style*  que se use. Saludos.